# Call mainActivity's method in LifecycleObserver

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, kotlin

I'm in trouble.

I would like to call my MainActivity's method from my LifeCycleManager ( which is a LifecycleObserver )  and perform simple XML modifications. But that crash because I'm trying to access to an XML value and main_activity.xml isn't fully created yet

First this is my LifeCycleManager :

```
class LifeCycleManager(context: Context) : LifecycleObserver {

companion object {
    var notif = NotificationManager()
    var onForeground = false
    var main = MainActivity()

    // If we are on MainActivity return true , otherwise return false
    fun isOnHomeController(context: Context?): Boolean {

        if (context == null || context !is MainActivity)
            return false

        return true
    }


var mContext = context

// WHEN THE APP BECOME ACTIVE
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
fun appComeBackFromBackground() {
    onForeground = true
    notif.cancelAllLocalNotifications(mContext)

    if (isOnHomeController(mContext)) {
        // Call the refresh dialog and print it
        main.appComeBackFromBackground("refresh", null)
    }
}
}
```

Here is my MainActivity method :

```
fun appComeBackFromBackground(status: String?, elementsadded: Int?)
{
Log.e("enterForeground", "App come back in Foreground")
if (status == null) return

when (status)
{
    "refresh" ->{
        val text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.refreshtext)
        text.setText("test")
    }
    else -> {
        return
    }

}
}
```

As you can see when my MainActivity Start , my Lifecycle get the event and go directly in my appComeBackFromBackground() method.
In it I'm calling my MainActivity method where I want to modify an element from activity_main.xml

That crash with theses :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mControllers.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to call observer method
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference

What can I do please? I really need to do it like this ( LifecycleObserver to MainActivity ). Thank's

**EDIT :**

I tried to call my MainActivity's method with delay like this :

```
Handler().postDelayed({
        main.appComeBackFromBackground("refresh", null)
    }, 5000)
```

And it crash too , even if MainActivity layout is loaded

Comment: You are trying to set text of a view that has not been created yet. Save the value you want to set in shared preference inside your life cycle method and later update the view inside the activity.

Comment: @MRah Exactly the view has not been created yet . The problem is that I don't want to save any particular data , I just want to perform some XML change when My LifecycleObserver tells me that I'm in Foreground

Comment: do you want to modify the xml layout permanently? Can you please explain your situation in more details?  To me it feels like, you want to achieve control over whether your app came from background or it's been created from scratch, am I right? modifying layout completely does not make any sense here though!

Comment: @MRah Sorry if it's not clear enough it's a bit complex. I would like to access to the xml layout . For example : I have an element in my XML who has visibility to "Invisible" , I would like in my MainActivity's method to findViewById() this element and set it to "Visible" in order to have it appears on my screen when I'm in my MainActivity

Comment: @MRah okey I will simply do it like you said , I will save in preference the value "refresh" for example and interpret it in my MainActivity when the layout will be fully loaded

Comment: please take a look into the answer. I wrote it in Java, please let me know if you need some more explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174832/discussion-between-mrah-and-manu13k).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I am writing this in Java, 
(This is the method if you don't want to save the data in preferences or storage)**

**Application Class:**

```js
public class TestApplication extends Application implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    private static String mStringToSet;
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //App is not from background, a new instance of your app           is created 
        mStringToSet="new_instance";
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }

    public static String getStringToSet() {
        return mStringToSet;
    }

  
    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
        if(activity instanceof MainActivity){
        //This is only called when the activity is destroyed not the application, so if the context is your desired activity then set the string here
            mStringToSet="refresh";
        }
    }

   //Implement other life cycle methods**
```

**In your activity:**

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String TAG="ACTIVITY";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if("refresh".equals(TestApplication.getStringToSet())){
            Toast.makeText(this,"From Background",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_TEXT_VIEW).setText("refresh")
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG,TestApplication.getStringToSet());
            Toast.makeText(this,"Not from background",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           (TextView)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_TEXT_VIEW).setText("new_instance")
        }

    }
}
     //Implement other life cycle methods
}
```

Comment: I clearly understand. It seems to be good , I will take a look at this in details and I will choose one of your two answers. Thank you man